# Assigning sliced DataFrame into another sliced DataFrame of the same size gives: ValueError, Incompatible indexer with Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply the labels from one DataFrame (`df2`) into another (`df1`) contingent on another value in the column of one DataFrame to land in the interval defined by a pair of columns in the other Datarame.

Here's the code,

```
import pandas
import numpy

df1 = pandas.DataFrame( { 'a' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b' : True } )
df2 = pandas.DataFrame( { 'c1':[ 2.0,3.1,5.2] , 'c2': [2.5,4.6,7.1] , 'l': ['x1','x2','x3'] } )

df1['l'] = numpy.NaN

for i in range( len( df1 ) ) :
    aVal = df1.loc[ df1.index[i] , 'a' ]
    is_in_c1c2 = ( df2['c1'] <= aVal ) & ( aVal < df2['c2'] )

    if is_in_c1c2.any() :
        df1.loc[ df1.index[i], 'l' ] = numpy.squeeze( df2.loc[ is_in_c1c2 , 'l' ].values )

        # df1.loc[ df1.index[i], 'l' ] = df2.loc[ is_in_c1c2 , 'l' ] # ValueError, Incompatible indexer with Series


print( df1 )
print( df1['l'].map(type) )

>>>
   a     b    l
0  1  True  NaN
1  2  True   x1
2  3  True  NaN
3  4  True   x2
4  5  True  NaN
5  6  True   x3
0            <type 'float'>
1    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
2            <type 'float'>
3    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
4            <type 'float'>
5    <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
Name: l, dtype: object
```

I was surprised to find the exception on my first attempt `ValueError, Incompatible indexer with Series`. Why is this not supported, is this a result of mismatching indexes of the DataFrames or what exactly?

Is there a cleaner/vectorized way to do such an operation? The `.values` assignment came close but left me with the wrong element types so I had to squeeze them. Would be nice to get the primitive types here. I also made the example for one column but in reality I'm copying over labels from two columns in my source.

Comment: Is the output in your question the proper output, just with messed up types?

Comment: whoops, its the output before applying `numpy.squeeze` I must have grabbed the earlier console output by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use Pandas' `IntervalIndex`.

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df2['c1'], df2['c2'], closed='both')
df1['l'] = df2.loc[idx.get_indexer(df1['a']), 'l'].values
df1
>>>
    a   b       l
0   1   True    NaN
1   2   True    x1
2   3   True    NaN
3   4   True    x2
4   5   True    NaN
5   6   True    x3
```

Not sure how fast this is. If `df1['a']` really only contains integer then there is a faster way to do it.

I think your original `ValueError` was because `df2.loc[ is_in_c1c2 , 'l' ]` returns a `Series`. The error occurs when trying to assign a `Series` as a value in the dataframe. And `df2.loc[ is_in_c1c2 , 'l' ].values` returns an `ndarray`. The array contains only one value because there is only one match, but theoretically, there could have been multiple matches.

Comment: This is a great discovery for me in the pandas space, never knew about these interval bits of logic. Got a whole new field to study there, thanks for the great tip. Works like a charm, even with multiple 'l' columns simultaneously.